# Declaring events - "event must be of delegate type"

Tags: c#, events, methods, properties

I'm having a bit of trouble making an event. I'm getting the error `'IStregsystem.UserBalanceWarning': event must be of delegate type`,
but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

My interface, `IStregsystem` has the line `event UserBalanceNotification UserBalanceWarning;`, which I have to implement.

My event class looks like this (I'm just testing for now):

```
using System;

namespace Eksamensopgave2016
{
    public class UserBalanceNotification
    {
        public delegate void UserBalanceMessage(User user, decimal balanceDifference);
        public event UserBalanceMessage UserBalanceWarning;
        public User user { get; set; }
        private decimal _balanceDifference { get; }
        public void OnUserBalanceWarning()
        {
            if (UserBalanceWarning != null)
            {
                UserBalanceWarning(user, _balanceDifference);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Event fired!");
            }
        }
        public UserBalanceNotification(User user, decimal balanceDifference)
        {
            _balanceDifference = balanceDifference;
            SetValue(user, balanceDifference);
        }

        public void SetValue(User user, decimal balanceDifference)
        {
            if (balanceDifference != 0)
            {
                user.Balance += balanceDifference;
                if (user.Balance < 50)
                {
                    OnUserBalanceWarning();
                }
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just a bit uncertain about events. 
The lines

```
if (UserBalanceWarning != null)
{
    UserBalanceWarning(user, _balanceDifference);
}
```

Is `UserBalanceWarning` a method, or is it a property?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

My `IStregsystem`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Eksamensopgave2016.Core;

namespace Eksamensopgave2016
{
    public interface IStregsystem
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> ActiveProducts { get; }
        List<User> Users { get; set; }
        Queue<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
        InsertCashTransaction AddCreditsToAccount(User user, int amount);
        BuyTransaction BuyProduct(User user, Product product);
        Product GetProductByID(int productID);
        IEnumerable<Transaction> GetTransactions(User user, int count);
        List<User> GetUsers(IFilter<User> filter);
        User GetUserByUsername(string username);
        event UserBalanceNotification UserBalanceWarning;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Is UserBalanceWarning a method, or is it a property?* It is an event.

Comment: Can you show your code for IStregsystem and UserBalanceNotification?

Comment: @Nikolay I already have my entire UserBalanceNotification.cs file in the OP. I have edited the post to include IStregsystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IStregsystem interface, you're using a class type (UserBalanceNotification) as event handler. This will give the mentioned compile time error.

The handler for an event should be a delegate type. You can look at your UserBalanceNotification class for the correct way.

```
public class ClassWithEvent
{
    public delegate void CustomEventHandler(User user, decimal balanceDifference);
    public event CustomEventHandler CustomEvent;

    private void FireCustomEvent(User user, decimal balanceDifference)
    {
        if (CustomEvent != null)
        {
            CustomEvent(user, balanceDifference);
        }
    }
}
```

Register to the event with the following code:

```
public class ClassUsingEvent
{
    private ClassWithEvent _classWithEvent;

    public ClassUsingEvent()
    {
        _classWithEvent = new ClassWithEvent();
        _classWithEvent.CustomEvent += HandleCustomEvent;
    }

    void HandleCustomEvent(User user, decimal balanceDifference)
    {
        // handle event
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will have to look a bit more into it, but I really appreciate your answer!